# Convert pseudo code to valid SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to convert the below code into a valid SQL statement.

I have tried multiple Update statements but then realized I could be using an updated value in a later update statement. This could result in multiple updates but the original code only updates once.
I also tried CASE WHEN but I can't find a way to allow CASE to update either Annuitant_1_DOB or Owner_DOB.

```
If B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch = 1 then
   If (ISNULL(Annuitant_1_DOB) or Annuitant_1_DOB < '1/1/1901') and ISNULL(Owner_DOB) = False then
      Annuitant_1_DOB = Owner_DOB
   Else
      Owner_DOB = Annuitant_1_DOB
   End If
Else
   If (ISNULL(Owner_DOB) or Owner_DOB < '1/1/1901') and ISNULL(Annuitant_1_DOB) = False then
      Owner_DOB = Annuitant_1_DOB
   Else
      Annuitant_1_DOB = Owner_DOB
   End IF
End IF
```

The end SQL should operate just like an IF statement and only make 1 update to the data.
Thanks

Attempted Code:

```
--If joint_annuitant_switch_Exhibit = 1 then
--   If (ISNULL(DOBofAnnuitant1) or DOBofAnnuitant1 < '1/1/1901') and ISNULL(DOBofOwner) = False then
Update [INS_VAL_SANDBOX].[dbo].[VA_Download]
SET Annuitant_1_DOB = Owner_DOB
Where (Annuitant_1_DOB IS NULL or Annuitant_1_DOB < '1/1/1901') and Owner_DOB IS NOT NULL and B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch = '1'
--  Else
Update [INS_VAL_SANDBOX].[dbo].[VA_Download]
SET Owner_DOB = Annuitant_1_DOB
Where (Annuitant_1_DOB IS NOT NULL or Annuitant_1_DOB >= '1/1/1901') and Owner_DOB IS NULL and B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch = '1'
--Else
--   If (ISNULL(DOBofOwner) or DOBofOwner < '1/1/1901') and ISNULL(DOBofAnnuitant1) = False then
Update [INS_VAL_SANDBOX].[dbo].[VA_Download]
SET Owner_DOB = Annuitant_1_DOB
Where (Owner_DOB IS NULL or Owner_DOB < '1/1/1901') and Annuitant_1_DOB IS NOT NULL and B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch <> '1'
--  Else
Update [INS_VAL_SANDBOX].[dbo].[VA_Download]
Set Annuitant_1_DOB = Owner_DOB
Where (Owner_DOB IS NOT NULL or Owner_DOB >= '1/1/1901') and Annuitant_1_DOB IS NULL and B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch <> '1'
```

And Another attempt (obviously not working):

```
Select
CASE B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch 
    When 1 Then
        CASE WHEN (Annuitant_1_DOB IS NULL or Annuitant_1_DOB < '1/1/1901') and Owner_DOB IS NOT NULL Then Annuitant_1_DOB = Owner_DOB
        ELSE Owner_DOB = Annuitant_1_DOB END
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN (Owner_DOB IS NULL or Owner_DOB < '1/1/1901') and Annuitant_1_DOB IS NOT NULL Then Owner_DOB = Annuitant_1_DOB
        ELSE Annuitant_1_DOB = Owner_DOB END
    END
From [INS_VAL_SANDBOX].[dbo].[VA_Download]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks fine to me -- the only change I would make is to have a

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
```

at the start

and a

```
COMMIT;
```

at the end to make the whole process atomic.

How exactly did your code fail?

PS -- What type is B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch?  If it is character or varchar then your code is right if it is a number then you want to remove the quotes

```
  B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch = 1
```

Comment: Which one are you referring to, the multiple updates? I am afraid that I am potentially updating Annuitant_1_DOB in the first statement and then using it to set a value in the second statement (and third statement). I shouldn't be updating multiple values. I really only want one of the updates to run, not all of them.B1_Joint_Annuitant_Switch is varchar.

Comment: @JRDew multiple updates are fine if you use begin transaction and commit -- since the where statements will only allow the updates to happen to different records.  Without the being transaction it could be wrong if some other user came in and changed them between updates.  The transaction will insure it is atomic

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with the BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT. I will go learn more about it now. Thanks for the help. I was concerned that multiple updates would run on the same record since I was making updates as I went along but that doesn't appear to be the case. Thanks again.

Comment: Yep, I was just researching BEGIN TRANSACTION before marking as solved. Done now.